# How to get a profile picture from fb:friends selector

Tags: facebook

Im a Newbie to PHP and FBML(Facebook Markup Language).....so now im coding a Facebook app so I need to get profile picture and friend name when I select a name from FB:Friend Selector

Select a Friend `<fb:friend-selector uid="exclude_ids" name="pal" idname="friend_sel" />`

I use exclude_ids to see all friends in my selector so how to get profile picture? I can get name from this but how to get the profile pic large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you are already able to get the name, for picture, you can put new graph api to use for getting photo easily:

Example url for my pic:

http://graph.facebook.com/sarfraz.anees/picture

So  you should simply replace the `sarfraz.anees` above with the facebook id of a user to get his profile image.

So you can show the profile pic of a user like this:

```
<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/sarfraz.anees/picture" />
```

Answer (score 1):

/picture?type=large  or /picture?type=normal